# Problems with pywin32com module

Tags: python

I´m a brazilian guy!

I'm learning Python and in the course I'm taking I was asked to use the pywin32com module, but when I run the program I get the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\p017258\PycharmProjects\MiniCursoHashtag\MeuArquivo.py", line 2, in 
import pywin32com.client as win32
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32com'

I am using Windows 10 Pro 21H2 on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz 2.10GHz
64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: Did you install the package? `pip install <name>`

Comment: Question is too broad. You should provide some code that the community can help you to solve your problem. And try to just share what is essential to solve the problem.

I hope this helps you :)